# How to click on a input field and fire event in knockoutjs and test it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, knockout.js, jasmine

What I'm trying to achieve is that when user clicks on the input field, I would like the search bar to be on top of the page. I'm using `hasFocus` but it only works the first time the page is loaded after I click the search bar again the event is not called.

```
<div class=".home-search-panel">
    <input type="search" data-bind="hasFocus: searchInputFocus()" name="q" placeholder="@Global.SearchPlaceholderCopy" value="@Request.QueryString["q"]" maxlength="150" class="input-product-search" autocomplete="off" />
</div>
```

And here's my knockoutJs code

```
var searchInputFocus = function () {
    document.body.scrollTop = zepto('.home-search-panel').offset().top;
};
```

And I think this code is using DOM manipulation which is harder to test without using `jquery-jasmine` how to do something like this in a knockout way so i can properly test it?

Comment: try using click in place of hasFocus

Comment: Hi just tried that, it doesn't work.

Comment: can you please provide fiddler for this ?

Comment: Check out the "Knockoutjs context debugger" chrome extension. It lets you select an element and see the values of $data, $parent, etc. Very handy in your case to see exactly what broke.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My thoughts...

1. You should remove the () after searchInputFocus(), it should just be searchInputFocus
2. The hasFocus binding needs to return true or false. hasFocus doesn't check *if* a control has focus, it *makes* the control have focus if the binding parameter evaluates to true. So, if searchInputFocus returns true, then knockout will set the input box to have focus. There is a well explained example in the [documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/hasfocus-binding.html) that I really can't make any better. :-)
3. It sounds like what you really want is the event binding: `data-bind="event: { onfocus: searchInputFocus}"` In this case, the searchInputFocus function will be called when the input box has focus.
4. The click binding as suggested in the comments should work too. It may not have worked for you because you need to remove the () after searchInputFocus as mentioned in point 1 above. Although the click won't fire if someone tabs to the field.

Hope that helps.